# Caml Query problem, cannot complete this action

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, caml-query, query, where-clause

I am new in sharepoint development, Can anyone please help me find an error in this query?

I am using javascript to retrieve records.
The where clause is based on status and priority fields.

Query I am using:

```
'<View><ViewFields>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'Author\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/>' +
                '</ViewFields>' +
                '<Query><Where><And><Or><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/>' +
                '<Value Type=\'Text\'>Lodged</Value></Eq>' +
                '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Reassigned</Value></Eq></Or>' +
                '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Acknowledged</Value></Eq></Or>' +
                '<And><And>' +
                '<And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>High</Value></Eq><Lt><FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today OffsetDays=\'-1\'/></Value></Lt></And>' +
                '<And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Medium</Value></Eq><Lt><FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today OffsetDays=\'-3\'/></Value></Lt></And>' +
                '</And>' +
                '<And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Low</Value></Eq><Lt><FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today OffsetDays=\'-7\'/></Value></Lt></And>' +
                '</And>' +
                '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Author\' LookupId=\'TRUE\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'Integer\'><UserID Type=\'Integer\'/></Value></Eq>' +
                '</And></Where></Query>' +
                '<RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>'
```

An error I am getting:

> Cannot complete this action.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85543/discussion-on-question-by-muhammad-fahad-caml-query-problem-cannot-complete-thi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        '<View>'+
            '<ViewFields>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'Author\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'/>' +
                '<FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/>' +
            '</ViewFields>' +
            '<Query>'+
                '<Where>'+
                    '<And>'+
                        '<Or>'+
                            '<Or>'+
                                '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Lodged</Value></Eq>'+
                                '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Reassigned</Value></Eq>'+
                            '</Or>'+
                            '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Status\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Acknowledged</Value></Eq>'+
                        '</Or>'+
                        '<And>'+
                            '<And>'+
                                '<And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>High</Value></Eq><Lt><FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today OffsetDays=\'-1\'/></Value></Lt>'+
                                     '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Medium</Value></Eq><Lt><FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today OffsetDays=\'-3\'/></Value></Lt></And>'+
                                '<And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Priority\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Low</Value></Eq><Lt><FieldRef Name=\'LodgementDate\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today OffsetDays=\'-7\'/></Value></Lt></And>'+
                            '</And>'+
                            '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Author\' LookupId=\'TRUE\'></FieldRef><Value Type=\'Integer\'><UserID Type=\'Integer\'/></Value></Eq>'+
                        '</And>'+
                     '</And>'+
                 '</Where>'+
            '</Query>'+
            '<RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>'+
        '</View>'
```

Comment: does not worked

Comment: You can try creating your query using CAML Designer. Download it from - https://www.biwug.be/resources

Comment: the caml query designer worked, i have used this tool which helped in resolving it. https://github.com/sapientcoder/QuickCAML